# concept of using telegraf with aerospike and influxdb

Tags: nginx, influxdb, aerospike, telegraf

I'm learing the concept of telegraf. It's a system that collects data and will write it to influxdb. So I've setup a influxdb, a telegraf and an nginx which will create the logs. Telegraf will collect the logs and write it to influxdb.

But I see a lot of configurations which are also using aerospike. I don't see what aerospike is doing in this conecpt?

I see it configured as input plugin for telegraf:

```
[[inputs.aerospike]]
   servers = ["aerospike:3000"]
```

Am I wrong with the nginx part and is aerospike providing logs or how do I have to interpret this concept with using nginx, influxdb, telegraf and aerospike

Answer (score 2):

I would assume Aerospike is simply a potential source of logs to be ingested by telegraf...

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/aerospike

nginx is just another potential input plugin... here is the list apparently:

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs